# Questions regarding the proof of the Ito isometry

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation

I am trying to understand the proof of the Ito Isometry, but somwhow do not understand the follwing two steps:

Setup: $B(t)$ is a Brownian motion and $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{a\leq t\leq b}$ a filtration such that:

1. For each $t$, $B(t)$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t}$-measurable.
2. For any $s\leq t$, the random variable $B(t)-B(s)$ is independent of the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}_{s}$.

Let $\{a=t_1<t_2<\ldots<t_n=b\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ and $\xi_i, 0\leq i \leq n-1$, bounded random variables such that each $\xi_i$ is $\mathcal{F_{t_i}}$-measurable.

Then during the proof the author says

$E\{\xi_{i-1}(B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1}))\}=E\{E[\xi_{i-1}(B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1}))|\mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}]\}$.

Why is this true? I´ve looked through several properties of the conditional expectation in other books but could not find one that could explain this step.

Then later the author says (for $i<j$):

$E\{\xi_{i-1}\xi_{j-1}(B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1}))(B(t_j)-B(t_{j-1}))\}=E\{E[\xi_{i-1}\xi_{j-1}(B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1}))(B(t_j)-B(t_{j-1}))]|\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}\}\\
=E\{\xi_{i-1}\xi_{j-1}(B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1}))E[(B(t_j)-B(t_{j-1}))]|\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}\} $

The first equality then probably can be justified by the same explanation as above, but why is the second equality true? I know that $E[XY|\mathcal{G}]=YE[X|\mathcal{G}]$ if $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. But why is $\xi_{i-1}\xi_{j-1}(B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1}))$ then $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$ measurable?

Many thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}))$ holds for any integrable random variable $X$ and any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ (some authors call this "tower property")

Comment: "why is $\xi_{i-1}\xi_{j-1}(B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1}))$ then $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$ measurable?" Simply check the measurability of each of the three factors.

Comment: The tower property explains my first question nicely, I undertsand this now.

Regarding the second problem: $\xi_{j-1}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$-measurable aswell as $\xi_{i-1},B(t_{i-1})$ and $B(t_i)$ because $\mathcal{F_{t_{i-1}}}\subset\mathcal{F_{t_{j-1}}}$ and $\mathcal{F_{t_i}}\subset\mathcal{F_{t_{j-1}}}$ for $i<j$. So they are all $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$-measurable individually I guess. But what is the argument that their product is then $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$-measurable, too? (do you know a reference for this argument?)

Comment: @spike Do you know that the sum of $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$-measurable functions is itself $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$-measurable?  Also, the square of an $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$-measurable function is itself $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$-measurable.  Assuming you know the above two facts, then take two $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$-measurable functions $f$ and $g$.  Then $f + g$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$-measurable, and so is $(f + g)^{2}$.  To get that $fg$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$-measurable, just notice that $fg = \frac{1}{4}(f + g)^{2} - \frac{1}{4}(f - g)^{2}$.  Does this help?